# Live Updating of razor (cshtml) pages when site is live

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

On a live IIS web server, is it possible to update the /View/xxx.cshtml razor files and have those changes reflected without rebuilding and reuploading server?

Comment: You could edit them locally or via FTP.

Comment: What is it you want to change?  If you are changing how data is displayed and not what data is required within the model, then the answer should be "yes."  The .cshtml files are not compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure - just open the file and update it or FTP a new version to the server.  The views are not compiled into the DLL (unless you are using one of those Razor View Compiler add-ins).  As a result, they can be modified on the fly like any other content resource (CSS, JS, images, etc)

Comment: great!  thanks.  I did try that and it worked but I hate to do things based on "well it worked".  Not compiled is what I was looking for.

Comment: No problem.  I should say that I wouldn't make a habit of it because you are modifying files outside of your source control/dev environment, leading to potentially strange conflicts going forward.

Comment: The reason is it allows an offshore developer to make changes on html CSS without having visual studio.